# How to build an electron application for different Windows versions?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I have a problem with my Electron app. I want it to be build for win7 platform, but couldn't find any appropriate ways to do it.

I have built my app for win10 platform via github release. But there is no option to build it for win7. I've tried to use an electron-packager, and it somehow worked, I got an .exe file for win7, but then, when I was trying to install it, nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't build for a specific version of an OS, just build for a specific OS.

Electron [dropped support](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-23-0#dropping-windows-7881-support) for Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 with its **version 23**. So if you want your app to be compatible for these versions of Windows, you have to keep your version of Electron to **v22.3.27** (latest of v22) max.

You can also decide to maintain two versions of your app, so supported versions of Windows can have the latest version of Electron.